# ElasticSearch: Agregation on a datetime field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to get aggregated information from a datetime field:

- Get how many documents are there by month (NOT YEAR/MONTH!, ONLY MONTH): So, a 'groupby(month(datetime_field))'.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format` parameter of `date-histogram` aggregation and chose only `month` field in that. Your aggregation would look like

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "documents_by_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "1M",
        "format": "MM"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "documents": {
          //... your sub aggregation
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jordi May I know what was the reason for unaccepting the answer, is this not working for you?